# Attribute at my value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to create a click-able image that has a name,class and id, if I click on that image it should show the id of that image without using database or post.For example:

```
<div class='widget-content' style="min-height: 300px;">  
       <img src="images/icons/running.jpg" 
        id="runningDrop"
        class="droplink" />
       <img src="images/icons/swimming.jpg" 
         id="swimmingDrop"
         class="droplink" />
 </div>
```

If I click one of the images, it should display the id `swimmingDrop` or `runningDrop`.

Comment: while you tagged jquery this is jquery solution $('img').on('click', function(){ alert($(this).attr('id')) });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply `onclick="alert(this.id)"`

```html
<div class='widget-content' style="min-height: 300px;">  
       <img src="images/icons/running.jpg" 
        id="runningDrop"
        class="droplink" 
        onclick="alert(this.id)"/>
       <img src="images/icons/swimming.jpg" 
         id="swimmingDrop"
         class="droplink" 
         onclick="alert(this.id)"/>
 </div>
```

and as I said in comment while you tagged jquery this is jquery solution

```js
$('img').on('click', function(){ alert($(this).attr('id')) });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='widget-content' style="min-height: 300px;">  
       <img src="images/icons/running.jpg" 
        id="runningDrop"
        class="droplink"/>
       <img src="images/icons/swimming.jpg" 
         id="swimmingDrop"
         class="droplink"/>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank's! it's really help me i hope i can become like you guy'z

Comment: @DitNik 1st your welcome  2nd I recommend https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNb8T5NBdQg&list=PL6B08BAA57B5C7810 to learn jquery .. 3rd Good Luck :)

Comment: i was wondering can you teach me in how can i assign it in a particular input in my form as it's value

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using jquery as it will make life easier:

```
$('img').on({
    click: function(){
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank it really help me a lot i try to learn more about jquery!

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>sample Page</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('img').click(function () {
                alert($(this).attr("id"));
            });

        });


    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class='widget-content' style="min-height: 300px;">  
       <img src="images/icons/running.jpg" 
        id="runningDrop"
        class="droplink" />
       <img src="images/icons/swimming.jpg" 
         id="swimmingDrop"
         class="droplink" />
 </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```